# NServiceBus 3.3 SuppressDTC workarounds

Tags: .net, nservicebus

If I use SuppressDTC in NSB 3, what do I need to do if there is an error? I get that I need to do some things for myself (fail to error queue or sendlocal for retries), but I don't see any built-in option to send to the error queue etc.

Should I literally `Bus.Send(failedMessage, errorQueueNameAsLoadedFromConfig);` and `Bus.SendLocal()` to fail and retry?

Answer (score 0):

I tested the scenario setting up the endpoint as:

```
public class EndpointConfig : IConfigureThisEndpoint, AsA_Server, IWantCustomInitialization
{
    public void Init()
    {
        Configure.With()
            .DefaultBuilder()
            .MsmqTransport()
            .IsTransactional(false)
            .MsmqSubscriptionStorage()
            .DontUseTransactions()
            .SupressDTC();
    }
}
```

in order to suppress TXs, and yes you need to handle failures manually.
The question is why do you need to suppress transactions?

Comment: For performance, really. We were finding that distributed transactions were hurting us a lot, and the exact situation I was in would allow me to only "commit" the dequeing if the other work was completed okay.

Comment: got it, the DTC is almost a bottleneck in some situations, also be sure to fine tune logging that has an high impact on I/O perf.
http://milestone.topics.it/2013/07/nservicebus-high-load-performance-tricks.html